# passing url to another page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am going to create two pages.

The first page will be home.html On this page I am going to have a link which moved to page 2 layout.html and from there the url should be fired is this possible please?

Comment: url should be fired ? please explain more

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - can you clarify and also mention anything you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect to another page, use `window.location.href = "http://my/href.com";`. If you want to do this on page load, try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://my/url/layout.html";
});
```

If you'd like to open another window or tab when you visit the second page, try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    window.open("http://my/url/layout.html");
});
```

This will open your link in a new window (or tab, based on user settings, which you can't control).

Sorry if this isn't useful, but this is the best I can do without you being more specific as to what you're attempting to achieve.